# Get all product using rest api

Tags: integration

how to make request to get all products using REST API. I'm integrating salesforce - magento through apex controller. please tell me how construct the request.

Comment: I am using below way to get all products of the website. Upvote the answer if this is useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
$rootDirectory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; 
require $rootDirectory . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$params = $_SERVER;
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER); 
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager(); 
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface'); 
$baseUrl= (string)$storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
$mediaurl=$objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')
                    ->getStore()
                    ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

$collection = $productCollection->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', '1')
            ->load();

 $appState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$appState->setAreaCode('frontend');

foreach ($collection as $product){
    $result[] = array(
        "id" => $product->getId(),
        "name" => $product->getName(),
        "sku" => $product->getSku(),
         "description"=> strip_tags($product->getShortDescription()),
          "small_image" => $mediaurl.'catalog/product'.$product->getImage()
    );
```

}

Here you get all product in result array